# How to mount external volume on /Users

Tags: time-machine, external-disk, mount

I have been trying to migrate from an old Mac Pro with big internal disk to a new iMac with (small) internal SSD and big external Thunderbolt disk for a while and found no direct answer. I have a time machine backup on an external disk. My preferred solution would be to mount the external disk on /Users. Apple support (whom I chatted with) does not have an answer. How to go about this?

Comment: Why do you want to mount a TM backup to `/Users`? Do you want to restore the data from there or do you want to keep using the existing user homes directly on the external disk?

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear. I have a *new* external disk that is mounted on /Users, now trying to restore my previous backup on it, so have hooked up two external disks. Not 100% it is going to work though.

Comment: Ah, you want to restore an existing TM backup to a new setup where the `/Users` directories are on an external drive. My (already deleted) answer doesn't make sense then.

Answer (score 1):

Documenting my own solution here, but would be happy to hear whether others have tried this in different ways. There are just a few steps to consider.

1. Create a dummy user with admin permissions with home directory on the built-in /Users disk
2. Name your external volume to something, e.g. Home - it would normally then be mounted on /Volumes/Home
3. Find the Volume UUID for your external disk using `diskutil list /Volumes/Home`, let's say the UUID is XYZ
4. Now comes the magic, use the `sudo vifs` command to add a line to your (by default empty) fstab file, the line should look like this:

   ```
   UUID=XYZ /Users hfs rw 0 2
   ```

Finally, reboot your machine and you are good to go.

Caveat 1: if your external disk is missing or broken you will not have home directories, so do make a backup!

Caveat 2: if your external disk is missing and you do not have a dummy user (step 1 above) you will not be able to log in at all.

After this you may want to restore a time machine backup. However, Migration Assistant tries to outsmart you and checks the amount of available space for the root directory (which is small) rather than the externally mounted /Users directory. To circumvent this you have to use a two-step process:

5. Restore user details (accounts) but not their data by de-selecting all the data directories when restoring using Migration Assistant, after doing this you will have re-created users without most of their data files.
6. Using the command line tool tmutil you can restore without the check:

tmutil restore /Volumes/Backup/Backups.backupdb/PreviousMachine/PreviousDisk/Users/{joe,anne} /Users

(please run man tmutil before trying this and use the correct directory names).

Answer (score 0):

Your mount solution works, but I prefer a different setup leaving /Users and /Users/Shared on the boot volume. You can point an existing account at the mounted home folder easily:

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201548
- [Account on external HD](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/53820/account-on-external-hd)

This way you can still have a local admin account to run updates and install software that don’t follow the rules of not assuming a user folder is on the same volume as the system with a local admin account. Your method will break harder in these cases. Apple allows (and designed updates) to have only one off accounts not in the boot drive /Users as opposed to over mounting it entirely.